# Generic Delegate

Tags: c#, generics

I want to have a delegate for a method which takes one parameter and returns a result, both of the same type.
I also want the type to be determined by a generic type argument but the following syntax fails me.

```
delegate T SomeDelegate(T param)<T>;
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: How about `delegate<T> T SomeDelegate(T param);` ?

Comment: that won't work either.

Comment: Isn't this just a `Func<T.T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put`<T>` between the Delegate-Name and the open bracket: `delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(T param);`. After the close-bracket you can only say, which type `T` must be, to be sure the correct types are passed. For example:

```
delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(T param) where T : IDisposable;
```

Often this is necessary, to be sure that T is inherited by `Disposable`. So you later can cast `T` as `IDposposable` and call some method of the interface.

Notice, only interfaces can be user for filtering.

Comment: Class types can be used as constraints as well.

Answer (score 5):

The type parameter must be declared between the method/delegate name and the regular parameter list:

```
delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(T param);
```